# Sql joins and queries

Tags: sql, join, sybase

I have 2 tables in sybase

Table 1:

```
ID   CUR
---- ------
A    USD      
A    GBP      
A    HKD      
A    JPY       
A    CHF      
B    USD     
B    GBP
```

Table 2:

```
Pair     Base  Under
-------- ----- -----
USD/GBP  USD   GBP  
GBP/HKD  GBP   HKD  
USD/JPY  USD   JPY
```

I need help with a query that will return a pair of currency for each ID if both the base and Under are present for the ID in table1.

Comment: You can show us your unsuccessful attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select distinct pair From table2
    join table1 b 
       on b.CUR = t.bas
    join table1 u 
       on u.id = b.id 
          and u.CUR = t.under
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.do you know if i can use a where clause. I need to return entries based on  u.id value.

Comment: Yes u can add a where clause at the end

Answer (score 1):

use this query.

```
select  Pair  from Table2
where Base in (select CUR from Table1 ) 
and Under in (select CUR from Table1)
```

Comment: need to be the same id in both base and under joins I think..